# What does .json() function do in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

What does the `.json()` function in http requests in Angular2 do?

Example code:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getName')
.subscribe(res => this.names = res.json());
```

I guess it's similar to javascript's `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: The method comes from the Fetch spec, which is defined [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes a response from the Http call, and parses it (just like JSON.parse(..)). Notice, if the return is not json, it will throw an error.

Comment: One of the things that confuses me and a key thing to understand is that it doesn't appear to just convert the entire response to json.  It only converts the body of the response to json.  I found this important to differentiate because the response from an Http is actually a response object that contains body, headers, etc, but after calling res.json(), only the body object is converted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source code to see what it does. But as @uksz said, it just parses the json, using `JSON.parse`

The source code is this:

```
    /**
     * Attempts to return body as parsed `JSON` object, or raises an exception.
     */
    Body.prototype.json = function () {
        if (typeof this._body === 'string') {
            return JSON.parse(this._body);
        }
        if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            return JSON.parse(this.text());
        }
        return this._body;
    };
```